# How to get server certificate in java

Tags: java, android, ssl, self-signed

I am working on a client program(in android) which needs to communicate with a jboss server via SSL. Currently I have followed the instructions from http://blog.crazybob.org/2010/02/android-trusting-ssl-certificates.html to get the self-signed certificate and connect to the server. I am wondering if this can be done from java since whenever server certificate changes , I have to manually get the certificate and compile it into the code itself. I have also noticed that google chrome in android can do this. Any idea how to achieve this.
Thanks.

I am using this test code to get server certificate without success.

```
public class TestCert {
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    SSLSocketFactory factory = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory();
    SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(<ip>, <port>);
    socket.startHandshake();
    SSLSession session = socket.getSession();
    java.security.cert.Certificate[] servercerts = session.getPeerCertificates();

    List mylist = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < servercerts.length; i++) {
        mylist.add(servercerts[i]);
    }

    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    CertPath cp = cf.generateCertPath(mylist);

    FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/CertPath.dat");
    ObjectOutputStream b = new ObjectOutputStream(f);
    b.writeObject(cp);
}
}
```

Comment: You don't need to compile it into your code. You need to follow the advice given in your link, which loads it into a truststore. All you need to do when the server certificate changes is to update the truststore. But a CA-signed certificate would be a much simpler solution, and ultimately much cheaper too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you give me some test code. To update the trust store as mentioned in the link, I need to do a 'openssl s_client' to get the server certificate. I want to do this from java code. How to do that?

Comment: No, you don't want to do that from Java code, you want to do it from the command line. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: At last I have achieved the functionality in C openssl library and made native API in java using swig.